# Flask render_template() does not show home page after deleting entry in database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I build a CRUD app, which already works pretty good, but after deleting an entry in a database, the redirection (i.e. rendering the home template) to the homepage does not work.

```
def create_venue_submission():

name = request.form["name"]
city = request.form["city"]

try:
    venue = Venue(
        name=name,
        city=city,
    )
    db.session.add(venue)
    db.session.commit()
    flash("Venue " + request.form["name"] + " was successfully listed!")
except:
    flash(
        "An error occurred. Venue " + request.form["name"] + " could not be listed."
    )
    db.session.rollback()
    print(sys.exc_info())
finally:
    db.session.close()

return render_template("pages/home.html")
```

This works perfectly, redirecting works. However, the following does not (see comment on last line of code)

```
@app.route("/venues/<venue_id>", methods=["DELETE"])
def delete_venue(venue_id):

    try:
        venue_to_delete = Venue.query.get(venue_id)
        db.session.delete(venue_to_delete)
        db.session.commit()
        print("delete that crap")
        flash(f"Venue {venue_id } was successfully deleted")
    except:
        db.session.rollback()
        print(sys.exc_info())
        flash(f"An error occurred: Venue {venue_id } cound not be deleted")
    finally:
        db.session.close()

    return render_template("pages/home.html") ### This never gets triggered.
```

I trigger this route in the front end like this:

```
<button
  id="delete-venue"
  data-id="{{ venue.id }}"
  class="btn btn-default btn-sm"
>
  Delete
</button>
```

```
<script>
  const deleteVenueBtn = document.getElementById("delete-venue");
  deleteVenueBtn.onclick = function(e) {
    const venueId = e.target.dataset["id"];
    console.log(`DELETE /venues/${venueId}`);
    fetch(`/venues/${venueId}`, {
      method: "DELETE"
    });
  };
</script>
```

In the database the correct entry is deleted, but after that nothing happens. I have no idea, why this does not work. I can not see an error in the code itself. Can anyone help me or explain that weird behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use redirect instead of render_template-

```py
from flask import url_for, redirect

@app.route("/venues/<venue_id>", methods=["DELETE"])
def delete_venue(venue_id):

    try:
        venue_to_delete = Venue.query.get(venue_id)
        db.session.delete(venue_to_delete)
        db.session.commit()
        print("delete that crap")
        flash(f"Venue {venue_id } was successfully deleted")
    except:
        db.session.rollback()
        print(sys.exc_info())
        flash(f"An error occurred: Venue {venue_id } cound not be deleted")
    finally:
        db.session.close()

    return redirect(url_for("name of home page function")) ### This never gets triggered.
@app.route("/venues/<venue_id>", methods=["DELETE"])
def delete_venue(venue_id):

    try:
        venue_to_delete = Venue.query.get(venue_id)
        db.session.delete(venue_to_delete)
        db.session.commit()
        print("delete that crap")
        flash(f"Venue {venue_id } was successfully deleted")
    except:
        db.session.rollback()
        print(sys.exc_info())
        flash(f"An error occurred: Venue {venue_id } cound not be deleted")
    finally:
        db.session.close()

    return render_template("pages/home.html") ### This never gets triggered.
```

And in the front end-

```
<script>
  const deleteVenueBtn = document.getElementById("delete-venue");
  deleteVenueBtn.onclick = function(e) {
    const venueId = e.target.dataset["id"];
    console.log(`DELETE /venues/${venueId}`);
    fetch(`/venues/${venueId}`, {
      method: "DELETE",

    }).then(response => {
        // HTTP 301 response
        // HOW CAN I FOLLOW THE HTTP REDIRECT RESPONSE?
        if (response.redirected) {
            window.location.href = response.url;
        }
    })
  };
</script>
```

Special thanks to [Andreas Gelever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5929974/andreas-gelever) for the JavaScript part.

Comment: thats pretty cool - it works. I do not really understand why flask does not handle this for me and I also need that JS part.